# What's wrong with my code "beautifulsoup"? CSV is always empty

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
 import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get("https://www.shurgard.nl/en/self-storage-in-the-netherlands/alkmaar-hoorn/alkmaar-oudorp", headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')

products = soup.findAll(class_='storage-unit')

with open(r'C:\Users\Hosiwan\Desktop\python\aaaa.csv','w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = writer(csv_file)
    headers = ['Title']
    csv_writer.writerow(headers)

    for product in products:
        title = product.find(class_='price-current').get_text()
```

The output file only has "Title" written only without any other data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sure you want to do all that work with BeautifulSoup and writer, when there's an api and you can use pandas?

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36'}

api_url = 'https://www.shurgard.nl/en/api/stores/62/units'
jsonData = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers).json()

df = pd.json_normalize(jsonData['stores'][0]['units'])
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Hosiwan\Desktop\python\aaaa.csv', index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
      id                                            summary  \
0    771  In a unit this size you can store a few boxes ...   
1    770  In a unit this size you can store a few boxes ...   
2    554  In a unit this size you can store a few boxes ...   
3    891  In a unit this size you can store the content ...   
4    537  In a unit this size you can store the content ...   
5    885  In a unit this size you can store the content ...   
6    513  In a unit this size you can store the content ...   
7    889  In a unit this size you can store the contents...   
8    538  In a unit this size you can store the contents...   
9    893  In a unit this size you can store the contents...   
10   892  In a unit this size you can store the contents...   
11   514  In a unit this size you can store the contents...   
12   570  In a unit this size you can store the contents...   
13   894  In a unit this size you can store the contents...   
14   522  In a unit this size you can store the contents...   
15   900  In a unit this size you can store the contents...   
16   890  In a unit this size you can store the contents...   
17  1164  In a unit this size you can store the contents...   
18   761  In a unit this size you can store the contents...   
19   954  In a unit this size you can store the contents...   

                                          description sizeDefault  \
0   <p>For example, you could store the following ...           1   
1   <p>For example, you could store the following ...           1   
2   <p>For example, you could store the following ...         1,5   
3   <p>For example, you could store the following ...         2,5   
4   <p>For example, you could store the following ...           3   
5   <p>For example, you could store the following ...           4   
6   <p>For example, you could store the following ...         4,5   
7   <p>For example, you could store the following ...           5   
8   <p>For example, you could store the following ...           6   
9   <p>For example, you could store the following ...           7   
10  <p>For example, you could store the following ...           8   
11  <p>For example, you could store the following ...           9   
12  <p>For example, you could store the following ...          10   
13  <p>For example, you could store the following ...          11   
14  <p>For example, you could store the following ...          12   
15  <p>For example, you could store the following ...          17   
16  <p>For example, you could store the following ...          14   
17  <p>For example, you could store the following ...          13   
18  <p>For example, you could store the following ...          40   
19  <p>For example, you could store the following ...          50   

   sizeAlternative sizeDimensionDefault sizeDimensionAlternative  sizeGroup  \
0                1            1 m x 1 m                1 m x 1 m          1   
1                3            1 m x 1 m                1 m x 1 m          1   
2              4,5          1 m x 1,5 m              1 m x 1,5 m          1   
3              7,5          1 m x 2,5 m              1 m x 2,5 m          1   
4                9          1,5 m x 2 m              1,5 m x 2 m          1   
5               12            2 m x 2 m                2 m x 2 m          2   
6             13,5          1,5 m x 3 m              1,5 m x 3 m          2   
7               15          2 m x 2,5 m              2 m x 2,5 m          2   
8               18            2 m x 3 m                2 m x 3 m          2   
9               21          2 m x 3,5 m              2 m x 3,5 m          3   
10              24            2 m x 4 m                2 m x 4 m          3   
11              27            3 m x 3 m                3 m x 3 m          3   
12              30          2,5 m x 4 m              2,5 m x 4 m          4   
13              33        2,5 m x 4,5 m            2,5 m x 4,5 m          4   
14              36            3 m x 4 m                3 m x 4 m          4   
15              51         3 m x 5,75 m             3 m x 5,75 m          5   
16              42          3,5 m x 4 m              3,5 m x 4 m          5   
17              39       3,5 m x 3,75 m           3,5 m x 3,75 m          5   
18             120           4 m x 10 m               4 m x 10 m          5   
19             150           5 m x 10 m               5 m x 10 m          5   

    sizeGtm       promoGtm     discountGtm  isLocker  \
0    1.00m2  first month 1  online special      True   
1    1.00m2  first month 1  online special     False   
2    1.50m2  first month 1  online special     False   
3    2.50m2  first month 1  online special     False   
4    3.00m2  first month 1  online special     False   
5    4.00m2  first month 1  online special     False   
6    4.50m2  first month 1  online special     False   
7    5.00m2  first month 1  online special     False   
8    6.00m2  first month 1  online special     False   
9    7.00m2  first month 1  online special     False   
10   8.00m2  first month 1  online special     False   
11   9.00m2  first month 1  online special     False   
12  10.00m2  first month 1  online special     False   
13  11.00m2  first month 1  online special     False   
14  12.00m2  first month 1  online special     False   
15  17.00m2  first month 1  online special     False   
16  14.00m2  first month 1  online special     False   
17  13.00m2  first month 1  online special     False   
18  40.00m2  first month 1  online special     False   
19  50.00m2  first month 1  online special     False   

                                              url  \
0    /en/reservationform?storeid=62&productid=771   
1    /en/reservationform?storeid=62&productid=770   
2    /en/reservationform?storeid=62&productid=554   
3    /en/reservationform?storeid=62&productid=891   
4    /en/reservationform?storeid=62&productid=537   
5    /en/reservationform?storeid=62&productid=885   
6    /en/reservationform?storeid=62&productid=513   
7    /en/reservationform?storeid=62&productid=889   
8    /en/reservationform?storeid=62&productid=538   
9    /en/reservationform?storeid=62&productid=893   
10   /en/reservationform?storeid=62&productid=892   
11   /en/reservationform?storeid=62&productid=514   
12   /en/reservationform?storeid=62&productid=570   
13   /en/reservationform?storeid=62&productid=894   
14   /en/reservationform?storeid=62&productid=522   
15   /en/reservationform?storeid=62&productid=900   
16   /en/reservationform?storeid=62&productid=890   
17  /en/reservationform?storeid=62&productid=1164   
18   /en/reservationform?storeid=62&productid=761   
19   /en/reservationform?storeid=62&productid=954   

                                        imageUrlSmall  \
0   https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
1   https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
2   https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
3   https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
4   https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
5   https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
6   https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
7   https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
8   https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
9   https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
10  https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
11  https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
12  https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
13  https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
14  https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
15  https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
16  https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
17  https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
18  https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
19  https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   

                                       imageUrlMedium  \
0   https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
1   https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
2   https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
3   https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
4   https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
5   https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
6   https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
7   https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
8   https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
9   https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
10  https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
11  https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
12  https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
13  https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
14  https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
15  https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
16  https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
17  https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
18  https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   
19  https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   

                                             imageUrl             imageAlt  \
0   https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...     1 m² locker unit   
1   https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...    1 m² storage unit   
2   https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...  1,5 m² storage unit   
3   https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...  2,5 m² storage unit   
4   https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...    3 m² storage unit   
5   https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...    4 m² storage unit   
6   https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...  4,5 m² storage unit   
7   https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...    5 m² storage unit   
8   https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...    6 m² storage unit   
9   https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...    7 m² storage unit   
10  https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...    8 m² storage unit   
11  https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...    9 m² storage unit   
12  https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   10 m² storage unit   
13  https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   11 m² storage unit   
14  https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   12 m² storage unit   
15  https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   17 m² storage unit   
16  https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   14 m² storage unit   
17  https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   12 m² storage unit   
18  https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   40 m² storage unit   
19  https://shg-prd.azureedge.net/-/media/shurgard...   50 m² storage unit   

           thumbnailAlt                                          promotion  \
0      1 m² locker unit  {'hasFiftyPercentPromo': False, 'hasFirstMonth...   
1     1 m² storage unit  {'hasFiftyPercentPromo': False, 'hasFirstMonth...   
2   1,5 m² storage unit  {'hasFiftyPercentPromo': False, 'hasFirstMonth...   
3   2,5 m² storage unit  {'hasFiftyPercentPromo': False, 'hasFirstMonth...   
4     3 m² storage unit  {'hasFiftyPercentPromo': False, 'hasFirstMonth...   
5     4 m² storage unit  {'hasFiftyPercentPromo': False, 'hasFirstMonth...   
6   4,5 m² storage unit  {'hasFiftyPercentPromo': False, 'hasFirstMonth...   
7     5 m² storage unit  {'hasFiftyPercentPromo': False, 'hasFirstMonth...   
8     6 m² storage unit  {'hasFiftyPercentPromo': False, 'hasFirstMonth...   
9     7 m² storage unit  {'hasFiftyPercentPromo': False, 'hasFirstMonth...   
10    8 m² storage unit  {'hasFiftyPercentPromo': False, 'hasFirstMonth...   
11    9 m² storage unit  {'hasFiftyPercentPromo': False, 'hasFirstMonth...   
12   10 m² storage unit  {'hasFiftyPercentPromo': False, 'hasFirstMonth...   
13   11 m² storage unit  {'hasFiftyPercentPromo': False, 'hasFirstMonth...   
14   12 m² storage unit  {'hasFiftyPercentPromo': False, 'hasFirstMonth...   
15   17 m² storage unit  {'hasFiftyPercentPromo': False, 'hasFirstMonth...   
16   14 m² storage unit  {'hasFiftyPercentPromo': False, 'hasFirstMonth...   
17   12 m² storage unit  {'hasFiftyPercentPromo': False, 'hasFirstMonth...   
18   40 m² storage unit  {'hasFiftyPercentPromo': False, 'hasFirstMonth...   
19   50 m² storage unit  {'hasFiftyPercentPromo': False, 'hasFirstMonth...   

                                              pricing  
0   {'price': '€&nbsp;8,<div class='sup'>00</div>'...  
1   {'price': '€&nbsp;20,<div class='sup'>00</div>...  
2   {'price': '€&nbsp;25,<div class='sup'>00</div>...  
3   {'price': '€&nbsp;40,<div class='sup'>00</div>...  
4   {'price': '€&nbsp;44,<div class='sup'>00</div>...  
5   {'price': '€&nbsp;56,<div class='sup'>00</div>...  
6   {'price': '€&nbsp;60,<div class='sup'>00</div>...  
7   {'price': '€&nbsp;64,<div class='sup'>00</div>...  
8   {'price': '€&nbsp;83,<div class='sup'>00</div>...  
9   {'price': '€&nbsp;91,<div class='sup'>00</div>...  
10  {'price': '€&nbsp;102,<div class='sup'>00</div...  
11  {'price': '€&nbsp;110,<div class='sup'>00</div...  
12  {'price': '€&nbsp;138,<div class='sup'>00</div...  
13  {'price': '€&nbsp;147,<div class='sup'>00</div...  
14  {'price': '€&nbsp;156,<div class='sup'>00</div...  
15  {'price': '€&nbsp;206,<div class='sup'>00</div...  
16  {'price': '€&nbsp;208,<div class='sup'>00</div...  
17  {'price': '€&nbsp;243,<div class='sup'>00</div...  
18  {'price': '€&nbsp;492,<div class='sup'>00</div...  
19  {'price': '€&nbsp;603,<div class='sup'>00</div...
```

Comment: Oh wow that's actually alot faster and easier method, Thanks, i got one more question, Does it work with most of the websites or just those with an api shown through XHR only?

Comment: just where you see the requests in XHR.

Comment: What if i got other websites written in css and there's no api link? how i'm supposed to scrape data from these?

Comment: If they’re <table> tags, I’d first try pandas .read_html. Otherwise Then you’d need beautifulsoup. Do you have a specific site in mind that you want me to look at?

Comment: Also just to clarify something. The sites are written in html. CSS is just stying.

Comment: the other day i tried to collect data from ebay "https://www.ebay.com/b/Camera-Drones/179697/bn_89951" i tried with beautifulsoup,wrtie method and it was pain in the**

Comment: Btw i tested .read code with a table and it worked but i have no idea how to save it in csv file for example : import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html("https://www.espn.com/nba/standings")

Comment: Thx again, i had to add df[0].to_csv " with increment to choose the table needed, is there a possible way to lets say extract df[0 and 1] combined together instead of going df[0], then df[1], i dmed you through your email .

Answer (score 0):

your script is incomplete. On loop products, you don't write the product title.

Comment: Hi sle, thanks for answering, i tried to play around with my loop, yet no positive results, would you please write down your loop?

Comment: Did you have a result with products ?
you can add : print(title) inside the loop.
And also inside the loop, you can write the result on csv file.,3

Comment: that's my results "Process finished with exit code 0", looks like my "products" isn't catching any texts...weird